# A sequential characterization for the limit of a function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, proof-writing

Question:
$f$ is a real function. Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty \iff \forall$ sequence $\{x_n\}$ that diverges to $\infty,   \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x_n) = \infty$

This is what I've tried so far.
suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty $ and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence that diverges to $\infty$.
Then by assumption, we have $\lim_{x_n \to  \infty} f(x_n) \implies \lim_{n -> \infty} f(x_n) = \infty$.

conversly,
suppose for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ which diverges to $\infty,  f(x)$ approaches $L$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$ .
then, as $x_n$ approaches $\infty , f(x_n)$ approaches $L$ . which is a contradiction because $f(x_n)$ should diverge.
Therefore $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$.

I feel like my proof is incomplete.

Comment: Hello :). Please use "dollar"  for latex; example : "\to" gives $\to$.

Answer (score 1):

let's write down the definition:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty \leftrightarrow \forall A>0,\exists B :x>B \implies f(x)>A$$.Now let $(x_{n})$ be any sequence diverging to $\infty$, u need to prove that $f(x_{n})$ also converge to $\infty$,and u do this by verifying the definition:what does it mean for a sequence $f(x_{n})$ to diverge to $\infty$?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_{n})=\infty \leftrightarrow \forall A>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N} :n>N \implies f(x_{n})>A $$ In this way u prove that the LHS implies the RHS.To prove the revers implication ,u can prove the contrapositive:What does it mean for $f$ to not have limit $\infty$ ,when $x\to \infty$,u negate the property and u try to construct a sequence diverging to infinity ,but whose image  by $f$ doen't.

Comment: thanks. could you explain the reverse implication a bit more.

Comment: Sequences don't converge to infinity.

Comment: @JohnDoumain fact they do in the compactification,anyway I edited the post.

Comment: @bruhhbruh if the limit of $f$,when $x\to \infty$ isn't $\infty$,then $\exists A>0:\forall B>0,\exists x>B ,f(x)\leq A$,now for $B=n\in \mathbb{N}$,this will give us a sequence $x_{n}$ satisfying : $$ x_{n}>n ,f(x_{n})\leq A$$ ,so if the limit of $f$,when $x\to \infty$ isn't $\infty$,we can construct a sequence $x_{n}$ which diverge to infinity but its image doesn't diverge to infinity.

Comment: Do not repost the same answer to multiple questions.  If you believe that [one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4567996/) addresses two questions, only answer one of those questions, and flag the other as a duplicate.